# Android Studio新規プロジェクト作成でプレビュー画面が表示されない

Tags: android-studio

Android Studioでの新規プロジェクト作成時に[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のようなメッセージが中央下辺りに現れて、プレビュー画面が出てきません。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どのようにすればこの問題を解決し、プレビュー画面を出現させることができますか。

Answer (score 1):

AppCompat が入ってないか、依存関係に定義されて無いからだと思います。

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

↑こちらに記載の手順で、SDK マネージャで Android Support Library をダウンロードした上で、`build.gradle` に下記追記すると如何でしょうか？

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```